# Cannot format date column in dataframe to datetime and not filter on it as a consequence

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I wanted to play around a bit with the corona virus dataset of the new york times. 
I want to plot it and filter by date to only show the last weeks. However I get this error message:
`TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'bool' and 'datetime.datetime'` driven by this line: `df_toplot = df[df['state'].isin(top_states) & df['state'] > da]`. Somehow I can't manage to turn the date column into a datetime format, instead its format is pandas.core.series.Series. How can I change that?

```
import datetime
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nytimes/covid-19-data/master/us-states.csv")

df['date']= pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
print(type(df['date'])) 
#print(df['date'].iloc[1] > date_object)
variable = "deaths" # "cases"
#print(df.head())

d = pd.pivot_table(df, index= 'state', values= variable,aggfunc=np.sum)
top_states = d.nlargest(10, variable, keep='first').index.values
s = "2018-06-19 11:21:13.311"
da = datetime.datetime.strptime(s, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f') 
print(type(df['date'])) 
df_toplot = df[df['state'].isin(top_states) & df['state'] > da]
df_toplot.pivot(index='date', columns='state', values=variable).plot()
plt.yscale('log')
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you just made a small typo. You are comparing the date to the states column.

```
# Change this line
df_toplot = df[df['state'].isin(top_states) & df['state'] > da]

# To this (don't forget to separate conditions with parentheses)
df_toplot = df[(df['state'].isin(top_states)) & (df['date'] > da)]
```